# Add a custom Back Button in React JS that only works for the app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want to add a back button to my ReactJS app that will navigate to the last page and it was fairly easy to do. But the problem I'm getting is I dont want to get out of my app with the back button when at the last page. I mean if the previous page doesnt belong to my app then the back button should be deleted.
Eg: browserHistory is as follow:

> reactApp/page2->reactApp/page1->Youtube

At page2 the back button will navigate to page 1.Then at page1 the back button should be disabled because the next page in history doesn't belong to my app. 
So can anyone help me with that

Comment: You can check the domain URL, if not from your domain just disable the button.

Comment: Welcome, please add more details so that we can better assist you with a solution to your issue. Read up on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with writing solid questions.

Comment: Foxiris, how do I check the domain of prev URL?